# Loading many attribute-based images into divs

Tags: html, c, image, webserver, relationship

I come from no server-side programming knowledge, so I have an issue.  Here is the situation:

I have a large group of pictures, about 1000, that are related to each other in some way.  I have written a function in C that creates an index table of relation between each picture.  It is very long and complicated, no need to put it here, all you need to know: If they aren't related whatsoever, the index is 0, if they are very close, it goes up to 99, with 100 being the same picture.  I can output the table into any sort of file that would be useful for retrieval online.

Now, I want to use this idea for a website.  I have a domain and a file system, but I haven't messed with any server scripts or anything, because I don't know where to start.  I have an html/css setup with several divs set up in decreasing size, and my goal is that when a certain picture is selected, it will be loaded by the biggest div, and then subsequently load related images in descending order into the smaller divs.  I am not sure how to do this, both in terms of the 'relation' attribute and in terms of retrieving said attribute.  Thanks for your time, I know this is very long question so sorry.

edit: to avoid confusion, I only have a few total divs, not the thousand all at once haha

Comment: You should consider a JSON-based API.

Comment: @JohnConde nothing, I don't know where to start.  I'm now researching diodeus's proposal.  It would be really helpful for a starting place if nothing else